# checkpoint utm-1 edge concurrent users

Tags: users, checkpoint, utm

I am considering to buy a UTM-1 firewall. However, I didnt get exactly what concurrent users mean. There are three models for Concurrent Users 16/32 or Unlimited. What does this mean ? How is concurrent user measured ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each seperate IP address any machine on your network tries to cross the firewall with (even if it is blocked) counts as a single user.

Comment: Thanks James. Do you know what happens if this limit is exceeded ? Are packets dropped or put into a wait queue or something like that ?

Comment: It will mark those ips as blocked and log an error that you have exceeded your limit. from this handy faq http://www.cpug.org/forums/check-point-utm-1-edge-appliances/6341-utm-1-edges-faq.html